# php mysql_query insert into not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form method="post" action="updatescreen(2).php">
Name of company:<br />
<input type="text" name="artid" id="artid" size="50" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Insert" id="Insert" value="Insert" /><br /><br />

<?php
if(isset($_POST['Insert'])){
    $id = $_POST['artid'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('$id', )");
}

?></form>
```

The connection to the database is included so not mentioned here. The connection is working fine, that's not the problem.

The problem is: the php code doesn't work. The php code doesn't insert the data into my database. What's wrong?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 3):

You had a `,` after `'$id'`:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('$id')");
```

Your code is also open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should be using something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of the mysql_* functions, which are deprecated. With PDO, you can guard against SQL injections by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('$id', )");
```

to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('$id')");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have one comma too many.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('$id')");
```

In future, try printing the error, which will help you debug the problem yourself:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('$id')") or die(mysql_error());
```

And please use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of the `mysql_` functions, which are insecure and deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Insert'])){
    $id = $_POST['artid'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('".$id."')")or die(mysql_error());
}?>


  <form method="post" action="updatescreen(2).php">
Name of company:<br />
<input type="text" name="artid" id="artid" size="50" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Insert" id="Insert" value="Insert" /><br /><br />
```

And => think about the safety!

Answer (score 0):

Errors:

> ```
> mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('$id', )");
>                                              ^---not secure, potencial sql injection
>                                                 ^----not need ","
> ```

Use this code for more security (most of all better pdo or mysqli):

> ```
> if(isset($_POST['Insert'])){
>    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['artid']);
>    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('$id')");
> ```
>
> }